# Arch suspend when I close laptop lid?

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, macintosh, suspend, acpi

I'm in fluxbox on Arch on a Macbook 5,1. New to linux. I'm trying to get Arch to suspend when I close my laptop. Lately I've just been using `sudo pm-suspend`.

I installed slimlock, and inserted

```
button/lid)
    case $3 in
        close)
            #echo "LID switched!">/dev/tty5
         /usr/sbin/pm-suspend &
         DISPLAY=:0.0 su -c - username /usr/bin/slimlock
            ;;
```

in my /etc/acpi/handler.sh,
which I read to do [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid), but it doesn't work. I tried installing xscreensaver, but I get a weird error:

```
error: perl-lwp-mediatypes: signature from "Justin Davis (juster) <jrcd83@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
```

Comment: Did you try ``pacman -Syy`` before trying to install xscreensaver? And what laptop do you have?

Comment: yup didn't help

Comment: Temporary issue: http://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2012-August/029496.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install `archlinux-keyring` package to have all needed public key.

`pacman -S archlinux-keyring`

[More information here.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman-key#Initializing_the_keyring)

Also you should lock first, suspend later:

```
button/lid)
    case $3 in
        close)
            #echo "LID switched!">/dev/tty5
            DISPLAY=:0.0 su -c - username /usr/bin/slimlock &
            /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
            ;;
```

Comment: How does this approach differ from configuring lid off/on in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`? Do we need to configure both, or are they mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question is a little old, now the easiest way to do this is with systemd.

Use systemd-logind for this. see `man logind.conf`.

With `HandleLidSwitch` option you can tell it what you want it to do when lid closes.

`HandleLidSwitch=suspend`

The options can be one of ,

- ignore
- poweroff
- reboot
- halt
- kexec
- suspend
- hibernate
- hybrid-sleep
- lock

Answer (score 0):

Follow this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman

Being new to Linux and going directly to Arch is not a good idea. Take a look at Fedora/Ubuntu or Debian.

Ps: You need to generate the PGP keys for arch linux so you can add them.

Comment: But I was under the impression that installing (or updating pacman) did that automatically...

Comment: thanks, this helped getting xscreensaver. but that script still isn't running anything on lid close

Comment: @mtahmed Actually it depends on the installation you are using. Last time I installed using the new Arch version, I didn't need to do anything. If you do, you usually need; pacman-key --init ; pacman-key --populate archlinux.

JackStewart: I remember having the same problem with XFCE4. I The only way for me to close the lid was telling XFCE4 to suspend and not hibernate.
Maybe a hint, perhaps you tried laptop-tools from the repo? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop_Mode_Tools